# Check if file downloaded to resume the code

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a code that enables me to login a website with credentials. I have replaced those with hidden1, hidden2 and hidden3 in the code for privacy.
The code login to the website then navigate to specific page that has two drop down lists.
From the first list that has four options (this is fixed to four options), I select an option and after that the second drop down is updated according to list1
But List2 is changeable as the options are not known
The next step is to click a button that goes to another page with two elements that I clicked so as to export a pdf file.
Everything is fine till now.

The problem is that I have put waiting line for 15 seconds so as to wait for the download and I am searching for more efficient way to check if the file downloaded or not using selenium vba.

Here's the code

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim bot         As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim sList1      As SelectElement
Dim sList2      As SelectElement
Dim By          As New By
Dim fso         As Object
Dim myFolder    As Object
Dim objFile     As Object
Dim fil         As String
Dim fn          As String
Dim dteFile     As Date
Dim n           As Integer
Dim x           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer

Const DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY As String = "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Files"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Len(Dir(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY

With bot
    .SetPreference "download.default_directory", DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY
    .SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
    .SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False

    .Start "chrome", "http://primprep.emis.gov.eg"
    .Get "/"

    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1").SendKeys "hidden1"
    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3").SendKeys "hidden2"
    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2").SendKeys "hidden3"
    .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button2").Click

    .FindElementById("Button1").Click
    .Wait 1000
mLoop:
    n = n + 1
    If n = 5 Then Stop
    x = 0
sPoint:
    Set sList1 = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dedara").AsSelect
    sList1.SelectByIndex n
    .Wait 2000
    Set sList2 = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dschool").AsSelect

    For j = x + 1 To sList2.Options.Count
        If x + 1 >= sList2.Options.Count Then GoTo mLoop

        fil = Format(n, "00") & "-" & Format(j, "00") & "-" & Application.Trim(sList2.Options(j + 1).Text) & ".pdf"
        sList2.SelectByIndex j
        .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1").Click
        .Wait 2000

        If .IsElementPresent(By.ID("ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2")) Then
            If .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2").Text = "لا يوجد بيانات لعرضها" Then
                Debug.Print "No Data For This School >> " & Application.Trim(Replace(fil, ".pdf", ""))
                x = x + 1
                GoTo sPoint
            End If
        End If

        Do
        Loop While .FindElementsById("IconImg_CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_print").Count = 0
        .FindElementById("IconImg_CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_print").Click

        Do
        Loop While .FindElementsByCss("[id^='theBttnbobjid']").Count = 0
        .FindElementByCss("[id^='theBttnbobjid']").Click
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)

        'I need a way to check if the file downloaded or not instead of waiting for 15 seconds
        'as sometimes the file took no time and sometimes the file may took over 15 seconds

        Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY)
        dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
        For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
            If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile And fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "pdf" Then
                dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
                fn = objFile.name
            End If
        Next objFile
        If fn <> vbNullString And Not fso.FileExists(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY & "\" & fil) Then
            fso.MoveFile DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY & "\" & fn, DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY & "\" & fil
        End If

        .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button2").Click
        .Wait 2000
        x = x + 1
        GoTo sPoint
    Next j

    GoTo mLoop
End With
End Sub
```

I have searched for such a topic and found a link but it was for Java selenium. And I need to deal with VBA selenium.
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check for files count in DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY before download procedure code and then check again after it. If the count increased by one, so it is downloaded.
just an IDEA

i found a code that i used to count files for attendance . you can take an advantage of it

```
Sub Attfiles()

    Dim AttFolder As String, path As String, count As Integer
    AttFolder = "D:\attdata"

    path = AttFolder & "\*.xls" 'ممكن تغير الامتداد هنا

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("A5").Value = count
End Sub
```

Comment: Hossam Azab, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: Thanks a lot Hossam. I will try to adopt this idea. Thank you very much

Comment: i must have 20 reputations

Comment: So you have another 9 points :) .. wait for a member to vote you up. I first votes. Now you have 26 points